# How to shuffle jobs in a Resque queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have a queue named check_integrity and lots of jobs in it. When i run a worker for it it takes jobs first in first out order. Is it possible to shuffle the jobs in that particular queue? I need the worker to take jobs randomly. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I implemented this using delayed jobs feature of resque-scheduler(github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler). Jobs enqueued at random time intervals and i able to shuffle jobs. 

Here is code. @values = (1..60).to_a. Resque.enqueue_at(Chronic.parse("after #{rand(@values[@values.size-1])} minutes"),FetchSources,source_id).
Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: Can you answer the question and then mark it as the right answer so it's closed as "answered"?

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about this is by popping entries out of the queue, batching them up, shuffling the batch and then re-insert them:

```
key = "resque:queue:bulk"
total = Redis.current.llen(key)
batch_size = 5_000 # any value that is good enough for you

batch = []
total.times do |i|
  entry = Redis.current.lpop(key)
  batch << entry
  if batch.size == batch_size || i.succ == total
    puts "re-inserting batch..."
    Redis.current.rpush key, batch.shuffle
    batch = []
  end
end
```

This is really useful when you mistakenly enqueue several jobs that end up racing for shared resources, locks and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [plugin](https://github.com/seomoz/resque-unfairly/tree/) for the Resque. I guess this is exactly what you need.

Comment: I don't think so - this plugin randomizes queues, not jobs in a queue.

Comment: with this plugin you can add weight

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind monkey patching resque then you can use this solution:

```
module Resque

  # Monkey patch Resque to handle queues as sets instead of lists. This allows
  # use to get jobs randomly rather then sequentially.
  def push(queue, item)
   watch_queue(queue)
   redis.sadd "queue:#{queue}", encode(item)
  end

  def pop(queue)
    decode redis.spop("queue:#{queue}")
  end

  def size(queue)
    redis.scard("queue:#{queue}").to_i
  end
end
```

If are using rails create a file inside the initializers with that code and you will be set.

Answer (score -3):

you can use 
   [Delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question